# Dapper does not properly map rows selected with LEFT JOIN (splitOn)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dapper

I have two models Vendors and Users. Each user may or may not have only one Vendor.
Vendors may have several Users.

Models:

```
public class AppUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? FullName { get; set; }
    public string? Position { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public int VendorId { get; set; }
}


public class Vendor
{
    public int VendorId { get; set; }
    public string? VendorCode { get; set; }
    public string? VendorName { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public List<AppUser> CompanyUsers { get; set; }
}
```

SQL Tables:

[image: sql]

I need to select all Vendors with related Users (if such exists).
My query:

```
SELECT
    v.VendorId
   ,v.VendorCode
   ,v.VendorName
   ,v.Status StatusId
   ,(CASE
      WHEN v.Status = 0 THEN 'Draft'
      WHEN v.Status = 1 THEN 'Open'
      WHEN v.Status = 2 THEN 'Closed'
      WHEN v.Status = 3 THEN 'Blacklisted'
    END) StatusName
    ,au.Id
    ,au.FullName
    ,au.Position
    ,au.StatusId
   ,(CASE
      WHEN au.StatusId = 0 THEN 'Draft'
      WHEN au.StatusId = 1 THEN 'Open'
      WHEN au.StatusId = 2 THEN 'Closed'
    END) StatusName
  FROM Procurement.Vendors v
    LEFT JOIN Config.AppUser au
    ON v.VendorId = au.VendorId
```

and the result:
[image: result]

Because only Vendor with Id 20 has users, it appears 3 times, which is expected behavior. Now I want to use Dapper's `splitOn` function to map all users under vendor 20. I split by user's Id column.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Vendor>?> GetAllVendors(int businessUnitId)
{
    var currentUser = await _appUserService.GetCurrentUserAsync();

    var p = new DynamicParameters();
    p.Add("@UserId", currentUser.Id, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
    p.Add("@BusinessUnitId", businessUnitId, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);

    using IDbConnection cn = new SqlConnection(_sqlDataAccess.ConnectionString);
    return await cn.QueryAsync<Vendor, AppUser, Vendor>("dbo.SP_ZZZTest",
        (vendor, user) =>
        {
            if (vendor.CompanyUsers == null && user != null) { vendor.CompanyUsers = new(); };
            if (user != null) { vendor.CompanyUsers.Add(user); };
            return vendor;
        },
        param: p,
        splitOn: "Id",
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
```

And here is the result I get:
[image: dapper]

As a result, Dapper did not map Users under a single Vendor. But instead mapped each user as a List of users with a single item duplicating Vendor's data on 3 rows.

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is a common "problem". But it is really simple to solve once you understand the process behind the lambda call.

The lambda expression receives the three records created by the query and before calling the lambda, Dapper splits each record in two at the point of the *splitOn* configuration. In this process a new Vendor and new AppUser instance will be created for each row processed.

So the Vendor instance received at the second/third call is not the same instance of the first/second call. Dapper doesn't have this kind of processing logic (and I think it is right to avoid it from a performance point of view). So the code above, adds each AppUser to three different instances of Vendor.

It is up to you to 'discover' that the Vendor received contains the same data of a previous call. But it is easy to solve if there is some kind of unique key that identifies a Vendor (the PK of the record)

So this "problem" can be solved using a Dictionary where the key is the PK of the Vendor and you store each unique Vendor data passed by Dapper under that dictionary key. Then you could check if the Vendor data received is already in the Dictionary and use the dictionary instance to add the AppUser.

```
Dictionary<int, Vendor> result = new Dictionary<int, Vendor>();

.....

using IDbConnection cn = new SqlConnection(_sqlDataAccess.ConnectionString);
_ = await cn.QueryAsync<Vendor, AppUser, Vendor>("dbo.SP_ZZZTest",
    (vendor, user) =>
    {
        if(!result.ContainsKey(vendor.vendorId))
        {
            vendor.CompanyUsers = new();
            result.Add(vendor.vendorId, vendor);
        }
        Vendor current = result[vendor.vendorId];
        if (user != null) 
            current.CompanyUsers.Add(user); 
            
        return vendor;
    },
    param: p,
    splitOn: "Id",
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

// A VERY IMPORTANT POINT...
// You want to return the Vendors stored in the Values of the 
// Dictionary, not the Vendors returned by the QueryAsync call
return result.Values;
```

Comment: Very good answer. I saw an answer somewhere else, where instead of `return vendor;` they had `return null;`. I don't know if it makes a difference memorywise, but it makes it very clear, that the return of QueryAsync is not to be used, the contents of the dictionary is the real output.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Yes, you are right - I struggled to understand what happens under the hood. The problem is that I couldn't find API documentation, and for Dapper-related issues usually I refer to www.learndapper.com website, where only basic scenarios are described

Comment: I have two follow-up questions: 1. If I have the same column (property) names for the parent and child model (StatusId), how Dapper knows from returned SQL result which StatusId column should be mapped to the parent or to the child model?

Comment: If they express FK and PK of the relation it is not really relevant because the two values should be equal. But I think they follow the order in which the two fields appear. I'm sorry but, although I have been a longtime Dapper user I am not an expert on the underlying plumbing that makes everything work. You could post a new question though.